# Batch file to rename files to specific names

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So a quick explanation. We have hundreds of projects and in each of them and in every new project we have a program where we fill in a ton of information. From that we get 20 pdf files that are called `File_1`, `File_2` etc.

What I'd like to do is to rename the files as the example below with a bat file.

```
File_1 = abc.pdf

File_2 = xyz.pdf

File_3 = qwe.pdf
```

I want to specific in the bat file what I want `file_1` should be called and `file_2` etc. The files I get will always be called `File_1`, `File_2` etc and I always want them to be renamed the same. So each time I get those files I just run the bat file. Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a tour [How do I ask a good question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your files will always be called "file_1", "file_2" etc.??
If they are, then you can just write a file with a line for each file. For example

```
ren file_1 foo.pdf
ren file_2 bar.pdf
ren file_3 foobar.pdf
```

Note that as you didn't specify extensions for the original filenames, I haven't either.  You would want to put the full file name with extension, or use wildcards if appropriate, e.g. `ren file_1.*`.  (Be very careful with wildcards though, or you may end up trying to rename multiple files with the same name!)

You could check if the file exists first, and only run the ren on files that are there, or you could run it and let it error for missing files (though I'm sure other people will have reasons why you shouldn't).

You should also consider whether or not there will already be a file with the name you are trying to rename to, because if there the is then the rename will error and fail.

If your files will be different names daily, you will need to give more information as to what you have and what you need.

**EDIT - Response to comment below**

Copy (and complete) this code, and save it as 'rename.bat' or whatever you need.

```
@echo off
ren file_1 abc.pdf
ren file_2 xyz.pdf
ren file_3 qwe.pdf
<<repeat as necessary>>
```

The `@echo off` just stops the batch file from displayed the commands.  It will still display errors (if the file doesn't exist or if you try to rename a file to an existing filename).  You really should be looking at catching the errors and doing something with it, but if you can be 100% certain that the new filenames don't exist it will work.

Also worth pointing out that as I haven't used full file names, the batch file would need to be in the same folder as your file_1, file_2 etc.

You could use `move` to specify the full path of the original file, and a new path (it will move and rename the files), but you still have potentially the same problems with duplicate filenames etc.

I'm assuming you will end up with a folder containing file_1, file_2 etc. so you can just copy your batch file into the folder, run it, then move all your renamed files to where they need to go.  Then next time you need to run the file, your folder would only have in it the new set of file_1, file_2 etc. so you could copy in the batch file again, run it... and so on.

**EDIT2 - After thought for filenames including spaces**

It just occurred to me that your existing files (file_1, file_2 etc.) don't appear to have any spaces in the name, but your new filenames might (you didn't specify the names exactly).  If you have spaces if filenames, make sure to add quotes to the command e.g.

```
ren file_1 "my new file.pdf"
```

You can also quote your original filenames too (quoting both wouldn't hurt even if there are no spaces) so you could try

```
ren "file_1" "abc.pdf"
ren "file_2" "x y z.pdf"
ren "file_3" "qw   e.pdf"
etc.
```

Comment: I edited my question, sorry. I get the same number of files each time and they are always called file_1, file_2 etc and i always want file_1 to be called abc and file_2 xyz etc. Thanks for you answer. Do i just make a bat file and and add ren "filename" and then what i want it to be called?

Comment: @Erik see my edit above, but in principal yes, you can make a bat file with the ren "original filename" "new filename".

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Would you know how to use å ä ö? (Im from Sweden). And thanks again.